# Calculating interest on monthly deposits

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a short program that calculates interest on an amount deposited each month where the user enters the amount and the APR. I've gotten to declaring the variables, but I'm not sure where to go from there, this is what I have done so far.

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnBalance_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBalance.Click
    Dim Deposit As Double = CDbl(txtDeposit.Text)
    Dim APR As Double = CDbl(txtAPR.Text) / 100
    Dim MBalance As Double = 0
    Dim Balance As Double = APR * MBalance + Deposit
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail. For instance, Is the interest calculated daily and credited monthly? If so, you'll need to know the date of any deposit. and apply interest on the deposit.

Comment: @DeanOC The amount is deposited at the beginning of every month and the interest is calculated monthly as well. The output should look something like this: Month 1: 1000 Month 2: 2002 Month 3: 3015 etc. I'm sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure how to start a new line in the comments.